# Where can I get systematic problems and solutions for debugging?

Tags: malware, debuggers, crackme

I know PEFile headers, assembly language, and other basic stuff. 
I am looking for some site or book which systematically teaches me debugging and reversing. Something like "Let us C" for C language.
An ideal book/website would be which teaches a simple concept, and then provides a problem where these concepts can be applied to solve it. Then slowly add more concepts and provides questions which can be solved using those new concepts, and some hybrid questions which require a knowledge of multiple concepts (that have been taught already).

Answer (score 1):

You can read [this](https://beginners.re/RE4B-EN.pdf), which is an excellent book for reverse engineering and has many different things to try in many well-known arcitectures. If you want challenges, i know that [root-me.org](http://www.root-me.org) has some various difficulty reverse engineering challenges.